# When I select a row in MySQL using hibernate classes, it makes an update automatically

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to develop a blacklist for my users including several variables. So when a user sign up in my application, I check if some parameters are blacklisted or not.

The problem is that when I perform a select and the database find something that fits with my search, it automatically perform an update an clean that row.

This is the MySQL log:

```
   86 Query select * from blacklist where mobile_token = 'b'
       86 Query SHOW WARNINGS
       86 Query select @@session.tx_read_only
       86 Query update mydatabase.blacklist set email=null, iban=null, mobile_token=null, nif=null where blacklist_id=1
       86 Query SHOW WARNINGS
       86 Query commit
       86 Query SET autocommit=1
       86 Query SET autocommit=1
       86 Query set session transaction read write
```

This is my table:
[image]

My model:

```
package models.classes_hibernate;

import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Entity
@Table(name="blacklist"
    ,catalog="mydatabase"
)
public class Blacklist implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer blacklistId;
    private String mobileToken;
    private String iban;
    private String nif;
    private String email;

    public Blacklist() {
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="blacklist_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getBlacklistId() {
        return this.blacklistId;
    }
    public void setBlacklistId(Integer blacklistId) {
        this.blacklistId = blacklistId;
    }

    @Column(name="mobile_token", nullable = false)
    public String getMobileToken() {
        return this.mobileToken;
    }
    public void setMobileToken(String name) {
        this.mobileToken = mobileToken;
    }

    @Column(name="iban", nullable = false)
    public String getIban() {
        return this.iban;
    }
    public void setIban(String name) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }

    @Column(name="nif", nullable = false)
    public String getNif() {
        return this.nif;
    }
    public void setNif(String name) {
        this.nif =  nif;
    }

    @Column(name="email", nullable = false)
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String name) {
        this.email =  email;
    }
}
```

And my DAO:

```
package models.dao;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import models.classes_hibernate.Blacklist;
import models.pages.Page;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;
import play.Logger;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;
import play.db.jpa.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;

public class BlacklistDAOImpl implements MyAppCRUDDAOInterface<Blacklist> {

    @Override
    public void create(Blacklist entity) {
        JPA.em().persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Blacklist read(Integer id) {
        return JPA.em().find(Blacklist.class, id);
    }

    public Page<Blacklist> readAll(String orientation,int pageSize, int beginElementId)
    {
        Query query = null;
        List<Blacklist> blacklists = null;
        boolean areThereMore = false;
        Page<Blacklist> allBlacklists = null;
        int size = 0;

        if(orientation.equals("all")) {
            query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from blacklist",Blacklist.class);

        }

        if(orientation.equals("lt")) {
            query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from blacklist where blacklist_id < ? ORDER BY blacklist_id DESC",Blacklist.class);
            query.setParameter(1, beginElementId);
            size =query.getResultList().size();
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        }

        if(orientation.equals("gt")) {
            query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from blacklist blacklist_id > ? ORDER BY blacklist_id ASC",Blacklist.class);
            query.setParameter(1, beginElementId);
            size =query.getResultList().size();
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        }

        if (size>pageSize)
            areThereMore = true;

        try {
            blacklists = query.getResultList();

            if (orientation.equals("gt")) {
                List<Blacklist> reverseList = Lists.reverse(blacklists);
                blacklists = reverseList;
            }
            allBlacklists = new Page<Blacklist>(blacklists, areThereMore, "Blacklist");

            return allBlacklists;
        }
        catch(NoResultException nre){
            allBlacklists=null;
            return allBlacklists;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Blacklist entity) {
        JPA.em().merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Blacklist entity) {
        JPA.em().remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isManaged(Blacklist entity) {
        return JPA.em().contains(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        JPA.em().close();
    }

    public Boolean isMobileTokenBlacklisted(String mobileToken) {

        Query query = JPA.em().createNativeQuery("select * from blacklist where mobile_token = ?",Blacklist.class);
        query.setParameter(1, mobileToken);

        Blacklist blacklist;
        try {
            Logger.debug("Voy a comprobar");
            blacklist = (Blacklist)query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException nre){
            blacklist=null;
        }
        return blacklist != null;
    }
```

isMobileTokenBlacklisted call:

```
@POST
@Path("/api/user")
@ApiOperation(position = 3, nickname ="user", value = "Sign up new user",notes = "Minimum JSON required: ",
        response = AppUserJSON.class, httpMethod = "POST")
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
@Transactional
public static Result signup() {

    AppUserDAOImpl appUserDAO = new AppUserDAOImpl();

    AppUserJSON user = null;
    AppUser appUser = null;
    BlacklistDAOImpl blacklistDAO = new BlacklistDAOImpl();
    try {
        user = parse();

        String encrypt_nif = user.nif;
        String encrypt_authorization = user.parental_authorization;
        String encrypt_password = user.password;
        try {
            encrypt_password= EncryptUtils.encrypt(config1.getString("key"),user.password);
            if(user.nif!= null)
                encrypt_nif = EncryptUtils.encrypt(config1.getString("key"),user.nif);
            if(user.parental_authorization!= null)
                encrypt_authorization = EncryptUtils.encrypt(config1.getString("key"),user.parental_authorization);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        appUser = new AppUser(new Date(), new Date(),user.email.toLowerCase(), encrypt_password, user.mobile_token,
                user.mobile_device, 0, 0, 0, 0, encrypt_nif,
                false,"NOT_LOCKED", encrypt_authorization, 0, false);

        if (user.email == null) {
            return status (200, "email missing");
        } else if (blacklistDAO.isEmailBlacklisted(user.email)){
            return status(401, "Email is blacklisted");
        }

        if (user.password == null)
            return status(201, "password missing");

        if (user.mobile_token == null) {
            return status (206, "mobileToken missing");
        } else if (blacklistDAO.isMobileTokenBlacklisted(user.mobile_token)){
            Logger.debug("MobileToken blacklisted");
            return status(401, "Mobile token is blacklisted");
        }

        if (user.mobile_device== null)
            return status(207, "mobileDevice missing");

        else{
            appUserDAO.create(appUser);
            user.app_user_id= appUser.getAppUserId();
            return ok(Json.toJson(user));
        }

    } catch (IncompleteJSONException e) {
        return badRequest("IncompleteJSONException");
    } catch (DuplicateJSONException e) {
        return badRequest("DuplicateJSONException");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see where your `isMobileTokenBlacklisted` method is called? And I don't understand why your update query is done on `fairtime.blacklist` whereas you catalog is `mydatabase`

Comment: I have edited the database name, that was not the problem. I have edited the question with the isMobileTokenBlacklisted call and both of databases name are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where it comes from but we can find a way to correct some thing to improve your code and exclude definitely some queries.

- Be sure to use bracket around your if. It's not compulsory but is a way to make the code clearer
- In the signup method, the else is not **logical**. It only depends on the last if (mobiledevice test). You probably want to create your user if all test are wrong.
- Here you just want to test if you have any blacklisted element corresponding to your research. You can use COUNT function or even EXISTS which can be more efficient maybe.

You can use Debug mode to see where your update is done too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why but using count instead of select, it runs!